# How does Stack Overflow keep track of IP visits to URLs provided in some answers, and of consecutive logins?

Tags: discussion

I was reading that there are now "tag badges," and one of them indicated that if a number of unique IPs visit a URL you provide in an answer, you receive this badge.

How does the site engine store this information? Does it go into a database? It seems like so much work to create such a badge. Can someone elaborate on the mechanics of this feature?

Another question, and perhaps I should start a separate thread, but I'll try here: How does the site keep track of people logging in every day for 365 to award the Fanatic (I think it's that one) badge? Again, it seems as though some of these badges require a lot of work/data storage....

Comment: Welcome to MSO, Mel! You're right, your two questions are different enough that they should be asked separately. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69808/how-do-stack-exchange-sites-track-visited-and-consecutive-days) for the answer to your second question. Also, Fanatic only requires 100 consecutive visits, not 365.

Comment: Thanks Popular Demand, I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it the wrong way round.

It's visits **to** questions on Stack Overflow **from** links on other sites.

How is it done?

Take this question - see the "link" link just under the tags. This has the value (for me) of `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69800/59303` where "69800" is the question id and "59303" is my user id here on meta.

Visits to this question via that link will be registered against me with the IP address and date/time. If there are enough visits over the required time I'll get the badge.

Links to answers aren't presented in a trackable form, but can be constructed.

Comment: @Popular - cheers. I was caught out by the preview showing the url as I intended.